# beautiful soup extract a href from google search

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, google-search

A google search gives me the following first result on HTML:

```
<h3 class="r"><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470284889" rel="nofollow noreferrer" class="l vst" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNEv1W9YC2jcSKYdEo2kNqBMJ-Utmg','k89K9hF4cVNpxQYHtEKiUQ','0CCoQFjAA',null,event)"><em>Quantitative Trading</em>: <em>How to Build Your Own Algorithmic</em> <b>...</b> - Amazon</a></h3>
```

I would like to extract the link [http://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Trading-Build-Algorithmic-Business/dp/0470284889](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470284889) from this, but when I use beautiful soup to extract the information, I obtain

```
soup.find("h3").find("a").get("href")
```

I obtain the following string instead:

/url?q=[http://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Trading-Build-Algorithmic-Business/dp/0470284889&sa=U&ei=P2ycT6OoNuasiAL2ncV5&ved=0CBIQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEo_ujANAKnjheWDRlBKnJ1BGeA7A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470284889)

I know that the link is in there and I could parse it by deleting the /url?q= and everything after the & symbol, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [urlparse.urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) and [urlparse.parse_qs](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs), e.g

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = '/url?q=http://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Trading-Build-Algorithmic-Business/dp/0470284889&sa=U&ei=P2ycT6OoNuasiAL2ncV5&ved=0CBIQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEo_ujANAKnjheWDRlBKnJ1BGe'
>>> data = urlparse.parse_qs(
...     urlparse.urlparse(url).query
... )
>>> data
{'ei': ['P2ycT6OoNuasiAL2ncV5'],
 'q': ['http://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Trading-Build-Algorithmic-Business/dp/0470284889'],
 'sa': ['U'],
 'usg': ['AFQjCNEo_ujANAKnjheWDRlBKnJ1BGe'],
 'ved': ['0CBIQFjAA']}
>>> data['q'][0]
'http://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Trading-Build-Algorithmic-Business/dp/0470284889'
```

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for! Just wondering, why does BeautifulSoup() resolve the javascript into a different content than what my web browser shows? Does that mean I have to use the html5lib parser to get the right results?

Comment: @ejang: Sorry but i don't know how BeautifulSoup do it :( you can post a new question if you want that will be interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

To extract only the **first** result from the page you can use [`select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) by passing a CSS selectors or [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) `bs4` methods.

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-First-Occurrence-python-serpapi#bs4_result.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

# passing parameters in URLs
# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {'q': 'Quantitative Trading How to Build Your Own Algorithmic - amazon'}

def bs4_get_first_googlesearch():
    html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    first_link = soup.select_one('.yuRUbf').a['href']
    print(first_link)

bs4_get_first_googlesearch()

# output:
'''
https://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Trading-Build-Algorithmic-Business/dp/0470284889
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

The big difference is that everything is already done for the end-user: selecting elements, bypass blocking, proxy rotation, and more.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

def serpapi_get_first_googlesearch():
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": "Quantitative Trading How to Build Your Own Algorithmic - amazon",
      "hl": "en",
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()
    # [0] - first element from the search results
    first_link = results['organic_results'][0]['link']
    print(first_link)

serpapi_get_first_googlesearch()

# output:
'''
https://www.amazon.com/Quantitative-Trading-Build-Algorithmic-Business/dp/0470284889
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.