# Pull Data/Links from Google Searches using Beautiful Soup

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

Evening Folks,

I'm attempting to ask Google a question, and pull all the relevant links from its respected search query (i.e. I search "site: Wikipedia.com Thomas Jefferson" and it gives me wiki.com/jeff, wiki.com/tom, etc.)

**Here's my code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

query = 'Thomas Jefferson'

query.replace (" ", "+")
#replaces whitespace with a plus sign for Google compatibility purposes

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:wikipedia.com+" + query), "html.parser")
#creates soup and opens URL for Google. Begins search with site:wikipedia.com so only wikipedia
#links show up. Uses html parser.

for item in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class' : 'r'}):
    print item.string
#Guides BS to h3 class "r" where green Wikipedia URLs are located, then prints URLs
#Limiter code to only pull top 5 results
```

The goal here is for me to set the query variable, have python query Google, and Beautiful Soup pulls all the "green" links, if you will.

[Here is a picture of a Google results page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuM9O.png)

I only wish to pull the green links, in their full extent. What's weird is that Google's Source Code is "hidden" (a symptom of their search architecture), so Beautiful Soup can't just go and pull a href from an h3 tag. I am able to see the h3 hrefs when I Inspect Element, but not when I view source.

[Here is a picture of the Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV2uA.png)

**My question is: How do I go about pulling the top 5 most relevant green links from Google via BeautifulSoup if I cannot access their Source Code, only Inspect Element?**

PS: To give an idea of what I am trying to accomplish, I have found two relatively close Stack Overflow questions like mine:

[beautiful soup extract a href from google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368153/beautiful-soup-extract-a-href-from-google-search)

[How to collect data of Google Search with beautiful soup using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552470/how-to-collect-data-of-google-search-with-beautiful-soup-using-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a different URL than Rob M. when I tried searching with JavaScript disabled -

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=site:wikipedia.com+Thomas+Jefferson&gbv=1&sei=YwHNVpHLOYiWmQHk3K24Cw
```

To make this work with any query, you should first make sure that your query has no spaces in it (that's why you'll get a 400: Bad Request). You can do this using [`urllib.quote_plus()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus):

```
query = "Thomas Jefferson"
query = urllib.quote_plus(query)
```

which will urlencode all of the spaces as plus signs - creating a valid URL.

***However***, this does *not* work with urllib - you get a 403: Forbidden. I got it to work by using the [`python-requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module like this:

```
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = 'Thomas Jefferson'
query = urllib.quote_plus(query)

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=site:wikipedia.com+{}&gbv=1&sei=YwHNVpHLOYiWmQHk3K24Cw'.format(query))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
#creates soup and opens URL for Google. Begins search with site:wikipedia.com so only wikipedia
#links show up. Uses html parser.

links = []
for item in soup.find_all('h3', attrs={'class' : 'r'}):
    links.append(item.a['href'][7:]) # [7:] strips the /url?q= prefix
#Guides BS to h3 class "r" where green Wikipedia URLs are located, then prints URLs
#Limiter code to only pull top 5 results
```

Printing links gives:

```
print links
#  [u'http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Thomas_Jefferson&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFggUMAA&usg=AFQjCNG6INz_xj_-p7mpoirb4UqyfGxdWA',
#   u'http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Jefferson%25E2%2580%2593Hemings_controversy&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFggeMAE&usg=AFQjCNEjCPY-HCdfHoIa60s2DwBU1ffSPg',
#   u'http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Sally_Hemings&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFggjMAI&usg=AFQjCNGxy4i7AFsup0yPzw9xQq-wD9mtCw',
#   u'http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Monticello&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFggoMAM&usg=AFQjCNE4YlDpcIUqJRGghuSC43TkG-917g',
#   u'http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Thomas_Jefferson_University&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFggtMAQ&usg=AFQjCNEDuLjZwImk1G1OnNEnRhtJMvr44g',
#   u'http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Jane_Randolph_Jefferson&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFggyMAU&usg=AFQjCNHmXJMI0k4Bf6j3b7QdJffKk97tAw',
#   u'http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_1800&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFgg3MAY&usg=AFQjCNEqsc9jDsDetf0reFep9L9CnlorBA',
#   u'http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Isaac_Jefferson&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFgg8MAc&usg=AFQjCNHKAAgylhRjxbxEva5IvDA_UnVrTQ',
#   u'http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_1796&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFghBMAg&usg=AFQjCNHviErFQEKbDlcnDZrqmxGuiBG9XA',
#   u'http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/United_States_presidential_election,_1804&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj4p5-4zI_LAhXCJCYKHUEMCjQQFghGMAk&usg=AFQjCNEJZSxCuXE_Dzm_kw3U7hYkH7OtlQ']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the excellent response! I must ask though, if I wanted to assign a new variable to each of the link, how would I do so? x=wiki.com/tom, y=wiki.com/jeff, and so on. Again, thank you so very much for the response!

Comment: You could save them all in a list instead of printing them, or save them in a dictionary.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Python, and I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that, much less integrating it with the BeautifulSoup output format. You mind pointing me in the right direction? And I accepted your answer :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a list of `links` and shown the output - it's just a list of URLs as strings that you can then pass to a new `requests.get()` function call or do whatever you'd like with.

Comment: Thank you, again! Everything's worked out perfectly, I wish there was a "Reddit Gold" for Stackoverflow that I could give you :D Take care, and thanks again!

Comment: I beg to disagree, the code gives me an error: `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'quote_plus'`

Comment: @Georg in python3 it's `urllib.parse.quote_plus`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's no need to disable JavaScript. It's probably because you need to specify `user-agent` to act as a "real" user visit.

When no `user-agent` is specified while using `requests` library, it defaults to [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) so Google or other search engines understands that it's a bot/script and might block a request and received HTML will contain some sort of an error with different elements, and that's why you were getting empty results.

Check [what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) or see a [list of `user-agents`](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/).

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/GroundedCavernousCosmos#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get( 'https://www.google.com/search?q=site:wikipedia.com thomas edison', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

for links in soup.find_all('div', class_='yuRUbf'):
    link = links.a['href']
    print(link)

# or using select() method which accepts CSS selectors

for links in soup.select('.yuRUbf a'):
    link = links['href']
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Edison,_New_Jersey
https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Motion_Picture_Patents_Company
https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Thomas_E._Murray
https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb
https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Phonograph_cylinder
https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Emile_Berliner
https://wikipedia.com/wiki/Consolidated_Edison
https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/hello
https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Tom%20Alston
https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Edison_screw
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't have to figure out what HTML elements to grab in order to extract the data, understand how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines, and maintain it over time (*if something in the HTML will be changed*).

Example code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "site:wikipedia.com thomas edison",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
        print(f"Link: {result['link']}")
```

Output:

```
Link: https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Edison,_New_Jersey
Link: https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Motion_Picture_Patents_Company
Link: https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Thomas_E._Murray
Link: https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb
Link: https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Phonograph_cylinder
Link: https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Emile_Berliner
Link: https://wikipedia.com/wiki/Consolidated_Edison
Link: https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/hello
Link: https://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/Tom%20Alston
Link: https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Edison_screw
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

---

P.S. There's a [dedicated web scraping blog](https://dev.to/dimitryzub) of mine.

Comment: The `headers` trick was very usefull indeed, thanks. The bs4 code works perfectly (I did not try the SerpApi one). I am puzzled however by `'yuRUbf'`: it seems like a random string of characters, that Google may change anytime without notice?

Comment: @Georg That's great! `yuRUbf` is just a CSS selector class that is randomly (*it's a guess*) generated and **can** be changed over time without notice. [CSS selector reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) (*take a look at the very first example in the table*).

To use CSS selectors inside `bs4` you can use `.select()`/`.select_one()` methods. What's the difference between `select()` or `find_all()` you can find [here](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/comment/1gdam).

Comment: Any idea how long it's been `yuRUbf` and if it was something different ever before?

Comment: @user_11063709 Yes, it was different before according to what I saw from the older questions about scraping Google Search. I don't know how frequently they're changing. It's one of the drawbacks of `CSS` selectors because they can be changed later. If you can parsa data using [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), pick it. They're changing a lot less frequently if even changing at all.

Comment: @DimitryZub, thanks a lot for the additional tips and info! :)

Comment: @user_11063709 I'm glad that it helped you somehow! I've added additional info/explanation to the answer about `user-agent` and `select()` method which is more readable and flexible (*personal opinion*) than `find_all()`.  I'm currently writing a dedicated blog post about `CSS` selectors from a web scraping perspective (*pros/cons/usage, etc*), it will be available next week on my [dev.to profile](https://dev.to/dimitryzub) (*if interested*)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work with the hash search (`#q=site:wikipedia.com` like you have it) as that loads the data in via AJAX rather than serving you the full parseable HTML with the results, you should use this instead:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("https://www.google.com/search?gbv=1&q=site:wikipedia.com+" + query), "html.parser")
```

For reference, I disabled javascript and performed a google search to get this url structure.

Comment: When I do that I get a `HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`