# Is google search with python possible?

Tags: python, macos

Is it a little difficult to scrape google search result at present?
I want to find the first 5  url of one keyword in google with python3 on mac,my program as follows:

```
import requests, bs4 


word =input()


res = requests.get('https://www.google.co.in/search?q='+str(word))


page =bs4. BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")


result=page.select("a.href")


...
```

there are some failures:

> OSError: [Errno 65] No route to host
>
> requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError:
>   : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 65] No
>   route to host

how to solve these problems?

Comment: "Possible"? Yes. But it's a violation of Google's terms of service unless you acquire an API key from them and use it.

Comment: Google has systems in place to detect and stop web scrapers, but this may be a network connection error

Comment: Is your Python interpreter allowed to use your Internet connection? I remember my Mac show me a warning about OS X having blocked any in- and out coming connections from Python. Try to go to Settings and enable access with the firewall.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview re: docs for the *supported* mechanism.

Comment: I found a similar question about retrieving google searches with BeautifulSoup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589897/pull-data-links-from-google-searches-using-beautiful-soup). Apart from that, I wonder, can you ping google with the links you are generating? Are you replacing spaces with + in your query's?

Comment: (though "No route to host" generally means you've got an OS-level networking misconfiguration)

Comment: Look at This :
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-search It is a python Library that will help you.

Comment: thanks all of you, maybe i start from API key

Answer (score 0):

Scrapping Google Search web page is not impossible, you just have to study pretty well how your browser behaves and make your script use this information to *disguise* itself as a regular browser. This involves playing with headers, how your GET request is built, and probably some AJAX functions mimics and so on.

`requests` allows you to do a pretty well customisation of requests to accomplish this.

Comment: Any time ;). If you do more specifics question on how to work with requests, I could help you

Comment: could you give me one contact?

Comment: Hi Andy, you could find me here: https://ar.linkedin.com/in/rafaaguilar1987